# PHPStorm - Adding custom inputs to a file / code template

Tags: php, phpstorm

I LOVE PHPStorm. However, I'm looking to take the 'PHP Class' file template, and essentially add a custom field in the creation for 'Extended Class'. I see no way to do this.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT2: I asked a follow up but then figured it out by tinkering with it. My original question remains, however.

Comment: Do you mean actual file template .. or dialog window?

Comment: Eh... both? I'd like to make it so that the dialog window that appears when using a PHP template (i.e. 'PHP Class') has an input for 'Extended Class' as well as the other predefined inputs. I'd prefer to override the PHP Class template, but I noticed that doing so removes a lot of the other inputs that were in the predefined template. Does that make sense?

Comment: *"I'd prefer to override the PHP Class template, but I noticed that doing so removes a lot of the other inputs that were in the predefined template. Does that make sense?"* Example please (screenshots/file templates). What exactly gets missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot extend dialog window .. unless, *maybe*, via custom plugin (which has to be written in Java).
2. You can easily customize actual file template by adding new or removing existing elements -- **Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates | Templates --> PHP Class**. You can add any static text, use standard/built-in variables or perform some manipulations on values from built-in variables ... but any custom variables will be ignored (as dialog does not ask for their values).
3. Create and use separate file template -- this way IDE will ask for values for  those additional variables. Unfortunately functionality of "New PHP Class" dialog window (like sync name space/file name editing etc) are not available here as it will be a completely different dialog.

**P.S.**
Some related tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8265 -- currently there is no plans to extend this dialog with extra "Extends" and "Implements" fields.
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5207 -- not sure how relevant it is now (because originally it was asking about adding namespace) .. but overall it's still related
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9790